# how to initialize a constexpr reference

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, constexpr

I am trying to initialize a `constexpr` reference with no success. I tried

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr int& f(int& x) // can define functions returning constexpr references
{
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int x{20};
    constexpr const int& z = x; // error here
}
```

but I'm getting a compile time error

> error: constexpr variable 'z' must be initialized by a constant expression

Dropping the `const` results in

> error: binding of reference to type 'int' to a value of type 'const int' drops qualifiers

even though I had the feeling that `constexpr` automatically implies `const` for variable declarations.

So my questions are:

1. Are `constexpr` references ever useful? (i.e., "better" than `const` references)
2. If yes, how can I effectively define them?

PS: I've seen a couple of questions related to mine, such as [Which values can be assigned to a `constexpr` reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26121939/3093378) , but I don't think they address my questions.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> 1. Are constexpr references ever useful? (i.e., "better" than const references)

They are guaranteed to be initiailized before the program starts, whereas a reference to const can be initialized during dynamic initialization, after the program starts running.

> 2. If yes, how can I effectively define them?

A `constexpr`  reference has to bind to a global, not a local variable (or more formally, it has to bind to something with static storage duration).

A reference is conceptually equivalent to taking the address of the variable, and the address of a local variable is not a constant (even in `main` which can only be called once and so its local variables are only initialized once).

Comment: Ahh, ok, thanks! It works if I move `x` outside `main()`. However, why do I need to put the extra `const` in the definition of `z`?

Comment: They need to bind to something with static storage duration, which can be a local `static` or a global.

Comment: `constexpr` affects the reference, not the type it binds to, so to bind to a `const int` you still need a `const int&`

Comment: I'm not even sure that main can only be called once. Though it would certainly be highly unconventional, I don't think the standard forbids calling main like it was just another function.

Comment: @antred [basic.start.main]/3: "The function `main` shall not be used within a program. The linkage of `main` is implementation-defined.
A program that defines `main` as deleted or that declares main to be `inline`, `static`, or `constexpr` is illformed. The name `main` is not otherwise reserved."

Comment: @JonathanWakely so I guess the same  apply for pointers, i.e. `constexpr int* p;` implicitly makes the type of the pointer `int* const`.

Comment: @vsoftco From a language point of view, `constexpr` is a *decl-specifier*. I'm not going to go into detail, but you can put the rest together.

Comment: @Casey Interesting, I stand corrected. :o

Does the same rule apply for C, too? Because I recall a discussion on a C forum where a user had a recursive main function and claimed it was legal C. Not having found any evidence to the contrary, I accepted it and assumed that it was true for C++ as well.

Comment: @antred C and C++ are different languages with different standards so there are many things that may be legal in C that are not legal in C++.

Comment: @antred I'm no C expert, but a quick look at N1570 shows no similar restrictions. 5.1.2.2.3/1 Program Termination does say "If the return type of the `main` function is a type compatible with `int`, a return from the
*initial* call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the `main` function as its argument..." [emphasis added]. This would seem to imply that *non-initial* calls to main are compliant.

Comment: @T.C. *"which can be a local `static` or a global"* or a temporary whose lifetime is extended to static storage duration: `static constexpr int const& x = 42;` is fine. That's also why `static constexpr auto x = {1,2};` is accepted by clang++, but `constexpr auto x = {1,2};` is not (at block scope). (This implies that even `static constexpr const int& z = +x;` in the OP's code is legal.)

Answer (score 11):

So the problem is that a constexpr reference needs to bind to an object with static storage duration, which is covered in the [draft C++11 standard: N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) section `5.19` *[expr.const]* (*emphasis mine*):

> A reference constant expression is an lvalue
>   core constant expression that designates an object **with static storage duration** or a function

The [draft C++14 standard: N3936](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/b7b8ed08ba4c111ad03e13e8524a1b746cb74ec6/papers/N3936.pdf) changes the wording:

> A constant expression is either a glvalue core constant expression whose value refers to an object with static
>   storage duration or to a function, or a prvalue core constant expression whose value is an object where, for
>   that object and its subobjects:
>
> - each non-static data member of reference type refers to an object with static storage duration or to a
>     function, and
> - if the object or subobject is of pointer type, it contains the address of an object with static storage
>     duration, the address past the end of such an object (5.7), the address of a function, or a null pointer
>     value.

So changing the declaration of `x` like so would work:

```
constexpr static int x{20};
```

Answer (score 5):

Like [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614591/how-to-initialize-a-constexpr-reference#comment45532536_28614655) says, the initializer needs to be an object with static storage duration.

> N4140/§5.19/4 A *constant expression* is either a glvalue core
>   constant expression whose value refers to an object with static
>   storage duration [...]
>
> N4140/§7.1.5/9  A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration
>   declares the object as const. Such an object shall have literal type
>   and shall be initialized. [...] Otherwise, or if a `constexpr`
>   specifier is used in a reference declaration, every full-expression
>   that appears in its initializer shall be a constant expression.

In N3337, the wording is different.