# Can't use a class reference as a non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I am on a project where I have to use a reference to a constant templated object as a parameter of another object's template.

Simply put I would like to do this:

```
template<typename T>
class A {...}

template<typename T, A<T>& a>
class B {...}

int main(){
   const A<int> a;
   B<int, a> b;
```

Problem is I can't figure out how to make it happen and I need your help.

On visual studio, the above code will produce the following error : "C2971: a variable with non-static storage duration cannot be used as a non-type argument"

If I try to use `constexpr` instead of const, with the following changes :

```
constexpr A<int> &a = A<int>(3);
B<int,a> b;
```

I get the following error "C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant"

Well I did try a few things that I saw on other posts regarding similar matters but unfortunately did not find anything that could solve my problem.

I am most certainly doing something wrong but can't figure out what.

Thank you in advance for your help!

EDIT : I tried the answer but unfortunately, even if it seems to be ok at first, I got this error while compiling : C2970 : an expression involving objects with internal linkage cannot be used as a non-type argument. Which appear to suggest that I cannot use the template parameter in another file? (I separated all the classes in different hpp) Any ideas ?

**SOLVED**: To solve the problem I used the solution hereunder and (I assume because my class was in a separate hpp file) just put the keyword `extern` before it to have :

```
extern const A<int> a;
int main(){ B<int, a> b; }
```

And it works like a charm.

Comment: Related [how to initialize a constexpr reference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28614591/1708801)

Comment: It makes no sense. Template parameter can't be a reference.

Comment: Andrew: it is unfortunately imposed by the project so it has to be a parameter of the template

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it can, but to an object with static lifetime.

Comment: @Quentin Oops, I have not expected that it's possible.

Comment: @Quentin: thank you for your comment. Is there any way to give A<int> a static lifetime ?

Comment: @docky Declaring it as a global variable, a static class member, or (I think) a static local variable in a function (but the function will have to be constexpr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use local variables as parameters for template - type definition cannot be localized, it can be used outside local variable scope. But if you replace your template param to reference to global variable that would work:

```
template<typename T>
class A {
  public:
    A() {}
};

template<typename T, A<T>& a>
class B {
  public:
    B() {}
};

A<int> a;
int main(){
  B<int, a> b;
}
```

Comment: The OP is using a non-static variable so this answer does not cover the OPs issue.

Comment: that why VS says it's error - and solution is not use local variables

Comment: With no explanation this is a code only answer and thus a poor one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Andrey. Is there any possibility to find a solution that keeps the A<int> a; inside the main ?

Comment: So `a` now has static storage duration, now the problem is getting `a` to be non-local.

Comment: @AndreyStarodubtsev Unfortunately, even if it seems to be ok at first, I got this error while compiling : C2970 : an expression involving objects with internal linkage cannot be used as a non-type argument. Which appear to suggest that I cannot use the template parameter in another file? (I separated all the classes in different hpp)
Any ideas ?

Comment: hmmm.. I declared object, reference to which I want to use as parameter to template as `extern A<int> a;` in header with templates and it compiles ok. Even if it's declared in separate header, it still works. I use g++ (GCC) 4.8.1, by the way, have no VS under the hand, may be that's an issue?