# why rvalue can't assign to constexpr reference variable

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, constexpr

I have the following code

```
constexpr int into(int a,int b)
{
  int c=a*b;
  return c;
}

int main()
{
 constexpr int &n=into(5,5);

}
```

and I have read (in MSDN)

> The keyword `constexpr` was introduced in C++11 and improved in C++14. It means constant expression. Like `const`, it can be applied to variables so that a compiler error will be raised if any code attempts to modify the value.

After I read it, I thought that `constexpr` can be used in place of `const`, but for the above code I get a compiler error stating

> ```
> `int main()':
> invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from an rvalue of type 'int'`
> ```

When `constexpr` is replaced with `const`, it works fine.  I don't understand this behavior; can somebody shed some light?

Comment: A `constexpr` reference has to bind to a global variable. See answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28614655/1460794).

Comment: @flatmouse,thanks for the replay... one of the answer in the link says "A reference is conceptually equivalent to taking the address of the variable, and the address of a local variable is not a constant" here when i use const it binds. but not only to the constexpr.i believe the behavior of const and constexpr to a variable is same

Comment: The problem might be that the return value of `into` is not saved anywhere, but you do save a reference to that return value, so where does that reference have to point to?

Comment: Has it needs to be saved? has the function call don't save the result anywhere temporarily, has compiler RVO comes into play?

Answer (score 6):

Unlike `const`, which applies to `int`, the `constexpr` keyword applies const directly to the variable of reference type `int&`, which has no effect.

```
typedef int &int_ref;

int main() {
    int x = 1;
    int &a = x;          // OK
    int_ref b = x;       // OK, int_ref is 'int &'
    const int &c = 1;    // OK, reference to const int
    const int_ref d = 1; // error: type of d is 'int &'
                         // qualifier on reference are being ignored
}
```

`constexpr int &n` and `constexpr int_ref n` is the same, 
while `const int &n` and `const int_ref n` have the qualifier different.

Answer (score 3):

Expressions marked as `constexpr` will be resolved at compile-time, which will treat the result of `into(5,5)` as an `int` literal. As we know, references cannot be bound to an `int` literal in C++.

You could make this work by making `constexpr int x=into(5,5);` appear at the global scope and within the main creating a `constexpr const int` reference to `x` forcing `x` to be resolved before `main` is called which then allows a reference to be bound to `x`:

```
constexpr int into(int a,int b) {
  int c=a*b;
  return c;
}

// guaranteed to be resolved before main is called
constexpr int x = into(5,5);

int main() {
 constexpr const int& n = x;
 static_assert(n == 25, "whoops!");
}
```

To specifically answer your question, this is completely orthogonal to rvalues or move semantics, but rather is a nuance of `constexpr`.

If global scoping gives you heartburn, you could make `x` a `static` as well and put its initialization before its reference binding, which seems more natural to me:

```
constexpr int into(int a,int b) {
  int c=a*b;
  return c;
}  

int main() {
 // guaranteed to be resolved before main is called
 static constexpr int x = into(5,5);
 constexpr const int& n = x;
 static_assert(n == 25, "whoops!");
}
```

Comment: "*As we know, references cannot be bound to an int literal in C++."*, what references do you mean?

Comment: @erip,things not clear you said  'into(5,5) as an int literal. As we know, references cannot be bound to an int literal in C++.'  i believe calling the into() function return int&& which is an rvalue and it should be assigned to constant reference,  things went fine when i put             const int &n=into(5,5); inside main..if const can why can't the constexpr was the constexpr is missing something to deal with this case

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I mean references to `int` literals. :) `int& x = 25;` is not legal. You can certainly have `const` references to `int` literals, but that's different from the resolution of `constexpr` as I understand it.

Comment: @RichardGeorge `into` is going to return what you mark it to return. In this case, it's an `int` (which is what you want lest you feel the wrath of dangling references).

Comment: @erip then according to your reasoning it should be possible to write `constexpr const int&`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki There is still the problem of resolution times. It's quite legal to have `static constexpr const int& n = into(5,5);` because it's guaranteed to be resolved by the time `main` is invoked.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki If you feel I'm not explaining it well, I invite you to downvote and provide an answer. :)

Comment: @RichardGeorge Clarification: You are wrong in your assumption that `const` and `constexpr` are the same. `constexpr` means "known at compile time", `const` means "cannot be changed after per-iteration assignment".  `const int i& = n;` assigns i to whatever n is this time round, but we cannot modify through i. `constexpr i = 25` means that `i` can be elided and 25 substituted in its place during compilation.

Comment: @kfsone, its not my assumption ,it was what I read, if you look at the block I pasted from MSDN "The keyword constexpr was introduced in C++11 and improved in C++14. It means constant expression. Like const, it can be applied to variables so that a compiler error will be raised if any code attempts to modify the value."