# Use of constexpr and const in reference definition

Tags: c++, reference, constants, c++14, constexpr

I have seen declaring a reference variable as constant in C++ on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-different-ways-of-declaring-a-variable-as-constant-in-C-C++).

```
static constexpr const int& r = 3;
```

So, Why both `constexpr` and `const` used in single statement?

What is the purpose of that type of statement?

Comment: Useful reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/difference-between-constexpr-and-const What is the purpose? Demonstration, I think.

Comment: Similar question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614591/how-to-initialize-a-constexpr-reference.  `constexpr` applies to the reference and `const int` is the thing referred to, they have different meanings

Answer (score 6):

`const` variables are ones that cannot be modified after initialisation (e.g. `const int a = 1`).

`constexpr` variables are  [constant expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression) and can be used at compile-time. The use of constexpr for a variable declaration implies const.

However, in this declaration, `const` applies to the int, while `constexpr` applies to `const int&` (a reference to a const int).

Comment: "which means that the `const` is redundant" Hardly.

Comment: Unless memory fails me, since C++14 `constexpr` no longer implies `const`.

Comment: @AndyProwl That's for member functions.

Comment: A constexpr specifier used in an object declaration implies const ([constexpr specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr))

Comment: A reference is not an object.

Comment: Try removing `const` from the code in the question. It won't compile.

Comment: @Oktalist, you are indeed right. I corrected the answer

Comment: @Oktalist it does actually compile if you remove `const`

Comment: @Oktalist You also need to sub `3` with an lvalue but I dont think that is what OP was asking about (non-const lvalue reference cannot bind to rvalue, this is a separate issue to constexpr)

Comment: @M.M Obviously you can drop the `const` if you also change the initializer. My point stands: the answer was wrong to say the `const` was redundant, as removing the `const` changed the meaning.