# Why references can't be used with compile time functions?

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, compile-time, constant-expression

I have two snippets.

The first snippet:

```
#include <string>

template <typename T>
constexpr bool foo(T&&) {
    return false;
}

int main() {
    std::string a;
    if constexpr (foo(a)) {
    }
}
```

The second snippet:

```
#include <string>

template <typename T>
constexpr bool foo(T&&) {
    return false;
}

int main() {
    std::string a;
    std::string& x = a;
    if constexpr (foo(x)) {
    }
}
```

The first one compiles, but the second one does not compile (error message: *error: the value of ‘x’ is not usable in a constant expression*. Why? Why `a` is usable in a constant expression and `x` is not?

The command, used to compile `g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because usually a constant expression cannot evaluate a reference that refers to an object with automatic storage duration. Here I mean "evaluate" by determining the [**identity**](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#1.1) of the object, **not** by determining the value of the object. So even the value of the object `a` is not required in your example (i.e. no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied), `foo(x)` is still not a constant expression.

Note `foo(a)` does not evaluate any reference. Although the parameter of `foo` is a reference, it is not evaluated as an expression. In fact, even if it was evaluated, for example,

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool foo(T&& t) {
    t;
    return false;
}
```

`foo(a)` is still a constant expression. Such cases are exceptions as the reference `t` is initialized **within** the evaluation of `foo(a)`.

---

Related part in the standard (irrelevant part is elided by me):

[[expr.const]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2):

> An expression e is a *core constant expression* unless the evaluation of e, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> - ...
> - an id-expression that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and either
>
>   - it is initialized with a constant expression or
>   - its lifetime began within the evaluation of e;
> - ...

[[expr.const]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#6):

> A *constant expression* is either a glvalue core constant expression that refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant expression (as defined below), ...
>   An entity is a *permitted result of a constant expression* if it is an object with **static storage duration** that is either not a temporary object or is a temporary object whose value satisfies the above constraints, or it is a function.

Comment: @jackX Yes, it may be regarded as a full-expression sometimes but it is not an expression.

Comment: Is an id-expression that denote a name of an object not a glvalue?

Comment: @jackX It is a glvalue.

Comment: yup. so, `a` in the question,  its evaluation also determine an identity of an object.

Answer (score 2):

Because you can't know at compile time what value `x` will have, all you know is that it will point to `a`. What you are doing is checking the "value" of `x`, but the value of `x` is the address where `a` is and you can't know where `a` will be allocated nor an address is constant.

On the other hand you already know the value of `a`, it's an empty std::string.

This question contains some more details: [how to initialize a constexpr reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614591/how-to-initialize-a-constexpr-reference)

Comment: Then why the first snippet does work? Function takes it's parameter by reference, not value. Function can't take the `std::string` by value at compile time, because `std::string` is not a compile time type.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, In your both code sections, the evaluation context all require the postfix-expression to be a constant expression. The definition of function template `foo` satisfies the requirements of a `constexpr function` due to its parameter is of literal type.
id-expression `a` and `x` are all glvalue which evaluation determine the identity of an object, but the only difference is that, In your fist code. copy-initialize the parameter from `a` only require identity conversion, because of the following rules:

> When a parameter of reference type binds directly to an argument expression, the implicit conversion sequence is the **identity conversion**, unless the argument expression has a type that is a derived class of the parameter type, in which case the implicit conversion sequence is a derived-to-base Conversion

And it does nothing, due to
[[over.ics.scs#2]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.scs#2)

> As described in Clause [conv], a standard conversion sequence is either the Identity conversion by itself (that is, **no conversion**)

And the remain expressions are all constant expressions. So, for `foo(a)` this expression, it's a constant expression.

For `foo(x)`, because `x` is an id-expression of **reference type** that subject to this rule:

> an id-expression that refers to a variable or data member of **reference type** unless the reference has a preceding initialization and either
>
> > - it is initialized with a constant expression or
> > - its lifetime began within the evaluation of e;

The lifetime of `x` began before the evaluation of `foo(x)` and it isn't initialized with a constant expression because `std::string a;` is not a glvalue constant expression. If you modify the `std::string a;` to `static std::string a;`,then it will be ok.