# Reference fields in constexpr class

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr

**EDIT**: I was able fully minimize this question, thanks for feedbacks.

Now, i am working on a vector class(vector it is term from mathematics). This class has template for dimension and elements type. I am needing to define reference fields: X,Y, the syntax must do not require call brackets(`v.X() - incorrect solution`). My implementation for this:

```
#include <array>

template <typename Ty, size_t Size>
struct vector {
    std::array<Ty, Size> data;
    Ty& x{ this->data[0] };
    Ty& y{ this->data[1] };
};

constexpr vector<int, 2> const_context() {
    vector<int, 2> v1{ 1,2 };
    v1.data[0] = 1;
    return v1;
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto res = const_context();
}
```

If we comment x and y fields compile it is successful.

My instruments: Visual studio 2017 and C++ 17. The solution must be portable and do not depend on compiler.

Comment: what is the error? what is the meaning of "does not work" ?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, this is not feasible.  What is the rationale for such stringent syntax restrictions?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with g++ and clang++

Comment: Updated, please see

Comment: Create one block of code I can copy paste and see exactly what you are seeing.

Comment: and your whole problem can be reduces to just 5 lines of code: this is a proper mcve: https://godbolt.org/z/zgEp0L The rest of what you show is just a distraction.

Comment: How about reverse dependency between x, y, z and `operator[]`: `template <typename T, size_t Size>
class impl {
public:
    std::array<T, Size> data; T& operator[](std::size_t i) { return data[i]; };` And specialization: `template <typename T>
class impl<T, 2> {
public:
    T x; T y; T& operator[](std::size_t i) { assert(i == 0 || i == 1); return i == 0 ? x : y; };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be reduced to this:

```
#include <array>

struct X
{
    constexpr X() = default;

    std::array<int, 2> data{};

    int& x { this->data[0]};
};


int main()
{
    constexpr auto res = X{};
}
```

> ```
> <source>:14:20: error: constexpr variable 'res' must be initialized by a constant expression
>
>     constexpr auto res = X{};
>
>                    ^     ~~~
>
> <source>:14:20: note: reference to subobject of 'res' is not a constant expression
>
> <source>:14:20: note: declared here
> ```

The issue is that a constexpr reference can be bound only to objects with static storage duration (which `this` is not). See [how to initialize a constexpr reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614591/how-to-initialize-a-constexpr-reference)

So afaik it is not possible without making it a method (the `x()` syntax).