# Why is constexpr with std::forward_as_tuple not working?

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++20, stdtuple

Why is the following not compiling? This is somehow counter-intuitive (not to say `constexpr` concepts are confusing):

```
#include <tuple>

int main() {
    constexpr const int a   = 0;
    static_assert(a == 0, "Wups");
    constexpr auto t2 = std::forward_as_tuple(a, a);
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YKe6NA8RSluKf3XQ)
I assumed that `a` is a compile-time constant expression which is clearly the case as I can use it in `static_assert`.

**Background**: I wanted to continue with `constexpr` tuple of reference to feed to other `constexpr` functions to do some compile-time computations

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614591/how-to-initialize-a-constexpr-reference, and in particular *"A constexpr reference has to bind to a global, not a local variable (or more formally, it has to bind to something with static storage duration)."*.

Comment: If you want to do compile-time calculations creating/passing by value is probably equivalent in many cases.

Comment: Are references necessary for your computations?

Comment: no not really, I thought I can wrap already computed  constexpr values into a tuple of reference.