# Size of reference to std::array not available at compiletime

Tags: c++, arrays, static-assert, stdarray

I'm interested to know why the second `static_assert` in my code below doesn't work. It seems like even though the array `c` is a reference to `a`, the size of the array is embedded in the type, so it should be available at compile time.

```
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<int,2> a = {1,2};
    std::array<int,2> b = {2,3};
    std::array<int,2>& c = a;

    static_assert(a.size() == b.size(), "a.size==b.size"); // ok size of array is compile time constant
    static_assert(c.size() == a.size(), "c.size==a.size"); // compiler error "static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression"
}
```

Comment: does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614591/how-to-initialize-a-constexpr-reference

Comment: because `a` is not constant expression

Comment: I'm now interested why `std::declval<decltype(c)>().size()` works with MSVC, but not with clang nor gcc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> the size of the array is embedded in the type, so it should be available at compile time.

This is true. But regardless, `c` is not a constant expression and therefore expression that contains it as a subexpression cannot be a constant expression - except certain operators that interact only with the type of the operand such as `sizeof`.

You can get the size for example using:

```
static_assert(
    std::tuple_size<
        std::remove_reference_t<decltype(c)>
    >::value == a.size(),
    "c.size==a.size"
);
```

Unfortunately, it is not very pretty.

Comment: could probably wrap it into a derived template.. Tuple_size is nothing more than `integral_constant` which uses `sizeof()`, so  straight-forward `sizeof()` idiom works too, if `tuple_size` isn't included into implementation (it sometimes overlooked).

Answer (score 3):

Note, that if you move all declaration out of main function, code would compile. Why? Because `a` is automatic variable, so it's not really a compile time object and reference is not elided here, therefore neither `a`  nor `c`or `c.size()` are `constexpr`. For global variables location of `a` can be determined at compile time.

IF you try bind them within function like this:

```
constexpr std::array<int,2> a = {1,2};
std::array<int,2> b = {2,3};
constexpr const std::array<int,2>& c = a;
```

You'll get error that `a` is not a constant expression. Variant which still may compile:

```
#include <array>

std::array<int,2> a = {1,2};
std::array<int,2> b = {2,3};

int main()
{
    std::array<int,2>& c = a;

    static_assert(a.size() == b.size(), "a.size==b.size"); 
    static_assert(c.size() == a.size(), "c.size==a.size"); 
}
```

Comment: This behaviour just goes to show how ridiculous C++ can be.

Comment: @PaulSanders Russel's paradox  sound ridiculous too, but it is logical. We had created a run-time alias for "something" which was created run-time, but we ask question about properties known in compile time, using function  `sizeof()` call to which is sensitive to nature of object it is invoked with. The is no logical way to formulate rules how compiler have to divine that we ask about something it can deduce.

Comment: `size()`, not `sizeof()`, that's a typo