# constant expression of global variables and local variables

Tags: c++

for the program below, the constexpr variables in the global scope work fine, but when I define in as local variables, it gives compile error as "constexpr variable 'ci' must be initialized by a constant expression"

```cpp
typedef const int CI[3];
constexpr CI &ci = CI{11, 22, 33};
static_assert(ci[1] == 22, "");

int main(){ 
    typedef const int CI[3]; 
    constexpr CI &ci = CI{11, 22, 33}; //compile error
    static_assert(ci[1] == 22, ""); //compile error
}
```

As far as I have read from the standard, under [expr.const], it does not talk about the the requirements of scoping of a variables to be a constant expression. Can anyone explain to me why defined as a global variable it can be a constant expression but not as a local variable? Thank you.

Comment: It is because it's a reference.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more? what does it have to do with the reference?

Comment: In general constexpr references do not really make sense, because you still would need the object it refers to as constexpr too.  `inline constexpr int[3] CI{11,22,33};` should be enough to do everything you need (in header file, replace inline with static inside a source file).

Comment: When you place your "constexpr" inside a function the lifetime of the array would be determined by the scope of main which is runtime behavior. So the lifetime is not compatible with the lifetime of an object determined at compile time these constexpr objects have a lifetime that matches the lifetime of your program.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614591/how-to-initialize-a-constexpr-reference

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28614776/12002570) in the dupe [how to initialize a constexpr reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614591/how-to-initialize-a-constexpr-reference)